# Get value from brackets from an onclick

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to get the lat and lon from an `onClick` function?

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="findLocation('6.443663,3.419248');return false;" id="Lagos">Lagos, Nigeria</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="findLocation('3.15021, 101.707703');return false;" id="Kuala">Kuala Lupar, Malaysia</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="findLocation('24.9952447639, 55.0559356887');return false;" id="Dubai">Dubai, U.A.E.</a>
```

I would like to have the numbers from the `findLocation` function into an array if possible for each location.

**Added Note**
The `findLocation` function plots my locations on a map and focuses in on that location. I need to try get the lat and lon from each onClick and somehow get these to plot my points when the page loads.

```
function findLocation(address) {
    var address = document.forms[0].q.value = address;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
//          marker.setMap(null);
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why do you pass a string and not each of the numbers as single arguments?

Comment: @FelixKling I have a map that is blank, when a link is clicked the google map plots and focuses in on that location. I'm trying to show all the locations by default by extracting the coordinates from the `findLocation()`

Comment: Ah, so you actually want to iterate over all link elements and parse the `onClick` attribute value? How are those links generated? I would take a totally different approach and store the coordinates in a map (object) keyed by location. Then you can easily iterate over all coordinates and look up specific ones with `findLocation` when you need to.

Comment: Is the html markup given or do you generate it?

Comment: @FelixKling I have updated my code so you see what findLocation does. The map links are generated statically not dynamically

Comment: Which raises another question: If you already have coordinates, why use Google's geocoding service? It looks to me that you already have the position, so you could directly set the marker there, without making a call to `geocoder.geocode` first. If they are statically generated, then you could move the coordinates to an object in your JavaScript I guess.

Comment: Something like?
$('a').attr('onClick').each(function(index,element){ //parse and add to an array });
Not a pretty solution but I guess it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you looking for something like

```
var obj = {};
$('a').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.attr('onClick').replace('findLocation(\'', '').replace('\');return false;', '');
    var array = text.split(',')
    obj[this.id]= [parseFloat(array[0]), parseFloat(array[1])];
});
console.log(obj)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ck3NP/1/)